# SVN Reintegrate same branch to trunk multiple times

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

**The SVN book states the following:**

> Once you have performed a reintegrate merge you should not continue to
>   use it for development. The reason for this is that if you try to
>   resynchronize your existing branch from trunk later on, merge tracking
>   will see your reintegration as a trunk change that has not yet been
>   merged into the branch, and will try to merge the branch-to-trunk
>   merge back into the branch! The solution to this is simply to create a
>   new branch from trunk to continue the next phase of your development.

In my case I want to keep using the branch after the reintegration to trunk and continue reintegrating to trunk multiple times. I have done this and I have run into two main problems:

1. I keep getting weird tree conflicts when I try reintegrate.
2. I keep getting a message that says something like "Reintegrate can only be used if revisions 280 through 325 were previously"

How do I get around this issue if I want to be able to reintegrate from a branch multiple times?

Comment: So the book says "don't do it", but you still wanna do it? That makes no sense. Just create new branches from trunk after reintegrating, like it says...

Comment: I have a similar issue. I want to push fixes from my branch back into the trunk allong the way, but NOT reintegrate. Unfortunately, 1.8 automatically re-integrates, even if you dont want it to. I cant create a new branch, as all branches for all other projects have the same branch name. My problem is, a) now I have done this, I dont know how to UNDO it. b) how do I merge in future without re-integrating?  This is no --dont-reintegrate option. I have looked at --record-only, but this doesnt make sense for this case?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the --record-only merge option as explained in SVN book, section [Keeping a Reintegrated Branch Alive](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.reintegratetwice)

Note that from Subversion 1.8, this is no longer needed, as [automatic reintegration merge](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#auto-reintegrate) was introduced.

Comment: If I want to only merge from the branch to the trunk and never the other way, can I reintegrate multiple times the branch? Do I need to do the --record-only trick?

Comment: Yes, you can. On Subversion 1.7 you need to do the --record-only trick, while on Subversion 1.8 you don't need --reintegrate nor --record-only

Comment: The version is the one of the client or the server or both?

Comment: It's the client that needs to be version 1.8. Server must be at least 1.5

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a number of workarounds on Google but they made me nervous as 'hacks'. To address it I decided to do just what subversion is hinting at in the message. I went back to my branch and explicitly merged the specified revisions:

```
~/python/orb $ svn merge -r 650:693 https://paulwhippconsulting.slsapp.com/source/orb/trunk
~/python/orb $ svn commit -m 'merged revisions 650:693 from trunk'
Sending        occl

Committed revision 695.
```

Once I did this, I was able to return to the working copy of trunk and reintegrate the branch without any problems.

I hope this helps